# baseline alignment in subscripts that have superscripts

Tags: vertical-alignment, subscripts, phantom

How can I vertically align these subscripts?

[image]

the problem is that the second one has a hat and the first one not. I tried `\phantom` and other commands, but I'm unable to get the desired results.

[image]

EDIT: adding MWE

```
\bm{\sigma}=\{\bm{\sigma}_{1},\bm{\sigma}_{\hat{1}}\}
```

Comment: I tend to make a `\myhat` macro for this: `\newcommand\myhat[1]{\smash{\hat{#1}}\vphantom{#1}}`, basically it is typesetting the contents with the hat, ignoring the height an depth and then inserting the height and depth of the original without the hat.

Comment: BTW please always provide full (but minimal) examples with questions. Having code to copy and work on right away is a lot easier for those wanting to help.

Comment: @daleif I have not finded your message into chat and I with all honesty I have tried \mathstrut, \mathrel, your \smash and if you seen there is not \vphantom.

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't quite understand your comment. My comment does contain a `\vphantom` it is on the second line. It also helps with `$\myhat{b}^2$ such that the `^2` does not disturb the line spacing.

Comment: @daleif Ah, I have understood now. But before of my answer I have put +1 on the comment (if you prefer I sent you a screenshot), but considering I didn't fully understand your macro, I wanted to do something different. If you see almost all my answers are always synthetic and I don't give many explanations because of my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How by comment of the very good user @barbarabeeton there is the "baseline alignment in subscripts that have superscripts".

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,bm}
\begin{document}
\[\bm{\sigma}=\{\bm{\sigma}_{1},\bm{\sigma}_{\smash{\hat{1}}}\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These subscripts are base-aligned.  Often, it would be "dangerous" to smash the entire subscript, but since there is no superscript on the same base character, it's okay.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much lot lot lot. I have done many attemps to find the solution. I will remember your advice. Now I edit the answer.